# Flashbuilder : want to horiz. align components left, centered and right

Tags: apache-flex, alignment, flex4.5, flash-builder

I have a Flex app. and have a top banner where I have one graphic I want left aligned, one graphic I want to hug to the right, then some text I want always centered in between the two.  Which layout do I use to do this?

TY,
Fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a group with the default AbsoluteLayout should work fine for your situation you can set the left property for the thing you want to show up bumped off the left side, a right value for the thing you want bumped off the left side and the horizontalCenter property for the thing you want in the middle.  Alternatively you could use an HGroup (or rather a Group with a HorizontalLayout) then add the thing on the left, add a s:Spacer width=100% then the center object then another s:Space width 100% then the thing on the right, I believe either one will work.  If neither of these works for you post back with more detail about how you would like them to show up (a design comp).